# Unity C# Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get data from an `int` variable in `Unity` using C# code.
Below is the `C#` code I am using to get the `int`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class endGameMessage : MonoBehaviour {
public static int score2;

void Start () {
    GameObject thePlayer = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    gameScript game = thePlayer.GetComponent<gameScript>();
    score2 = game.score;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    Debug.Log (score2);

}
}
```

Below is the code from the other script I am trying to pull the data from.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class gameScript : MonoBehaviour {
//score
public int score = 0;
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    if(other.gameObject.tag =="hammer"){
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("pickUpMessage").guiText.text = ("Picked Up A Hammer");    

        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("collision detected hammer");
        audio.PlayOneShot(gotHit);
        score = score+10;
    }
     }
}
```

I can get the the `int` value to come across to the other script but its always 0 even if the `int` was meant to be 10.

My question is how would i keep the value across the scripts?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public static int score2
{
    get
    {
        return GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<gameScript>().score;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of possibilities.

**The first one is to set your Score as a static argument for you gameScript**.

- So you can access it anywhere just like that :

  ```
  int myScore = gameScript.Score ;
  ```
- And the declaration should be :

  ```
  public static int score;
  ```

**The second possibilities is far better if you want to save a lot of differents values from differents script.
In this case, you need to define a gameContext singleton.**

If you don't know what is this, you should take a look at singleton in C# :
   [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx]

Singleton will allow you to have a single instance of your gameContext. 
         In your case, your singleton will have a Score attribute. 
         And you will be able to get the value from any scene and any scripts.

This is the best way so far.

Answer (score 0):

`score2` is read once at start and then never again. `int` is an integral type in C# and thus passed [by value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bfft1t3c.aspx) i.e. it receives a copy. There several ways to solve this problem.

The easiest solution is to access the `gameScript.score` directly - it provides read/write access to everyone anyway. To encapsulate it you may choose to define a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

A better way could be to define a new class `GameStatus` which holds all relevant things. This can be implemented as [singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) for example.