# Can't find button in unity from script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a button named `PauseResume` with tag `pResume`. When I try to find the button from script with

```cs
GameObject obj = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("pResume");
```

or

```cs
GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("PauseResume");
```

I get `null` for `obj`.

Comment: any chance the button is disabled at the time you do the find with tag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity C# Null Reference Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549465/unity-c-sharp-null-reference-exception)

Comment: well it either doesn't exist in the Scene, is misspelled or it is deactivated the moment your calls are done.

Comment: Could you please send the whole script and maybe add a screenshot of your hierarchy.