# How to change int in another script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, integer

I had to write a code in the enemy script that when they collides with a bullet damage is taken. Now I want to change this int, (which defines the damage of the bullet) but how? I am getting errors.

enemy script:

```cs
public int bulletdamage;

public void dead()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}

public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.CompareTag("bullet"))
    {
        Debug.Log("loluhit");
        healthenemy -= bulletdamage;
        if (healthenemy <= 0f)
        {
            dead();
        }
    }
}
```

It's attached to the enemy, the enemy gets instantiated and gets a random number of live

Then there is the shootscript, where I want to change the int value, to let it be uncluttered:

```cs
public int bulletdmg;

void Start()
{
    GetComponent<health>().bulletdamage = bulletdmg;
}
```

I get the error:

> "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

What to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity C# Null Reference Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549465/unity-c-sharp-null-reference-exception)

Comment: @Lotan that would mean that all enemys loose hp doesn't it?

Comment: Don't edit "solved" into your question. Instead accept an answer. If necessary create an answer you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting this error on the `GetComponentInParent` line it's because the parent doesn't have the `healt` script.

Make sure the object parent have this script attached.

Make sure that `health` is typed correctly (classes used to start with capital letter).

Comment: but the enemy isn't a child or parent

Comment: Then why are you using GetComponentInParent? You should have a reference to the script/object you want, and get that component.

Comment: it was a test i used it by accident

Comment: and how do i get the reference/how to create it

Comment: Let me recommend you this series of video-tutorials made by the people from Unity, will teach you about basic stuff like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0Z7xc18CcA&list=PLX2vGYjWbI0S9-X2Q021GUtolTqbUBB9B